# Calling a method in else but not working

Tags: java

```
       } else {
            this.getSequenceDataWithPO(extractedData, extractedDateData);

        }
    }
    return hasbroData;
}

// Fetch data where po number is not null
/**
 * @param extractedData
 * @param extractedDateData
 * @return hasbroData
 */
private List<String> getSequenceDataWithPO(List<HasbroIssuanceAmmendExtractData> extractedData,
        List<HasbroIssuanceDateData> extractedDateData) {
```

I am trying to call getSequenceDataWithPO in else block. However while debuging when it get to else block it does not excute the method. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share a bit more code ? Does it enters the `if` block ? Have you set a breakpoint inside `getSequenceDataWithPO()` method ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Gaël yes it enter if block. and as soon it reach else block ...it goes back again to if. Yes i had set up break point over there as well. but never execute getSequenceDataWithPO

Comment: @Sam : if it enters the `if` block , why do you expect it to enter the `else` block ?! It's one or the other, not both...

Comment: @Gaël Yes you are rite....it is doing its if part correct. However once it is in else condition in a different case it should execute that method. which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

**`if`, `else if`, and `else` statements should be thought of like this:**

`if`: *if the following conditions are met, then execute these commands*

`else if`: *otherwise and if the following conditions are met, then execute these commands*

`else`: *otherwise, execute the following commands*

This means that conditional statements are executed in a chain. Once one of the conditions in an `if`, `else if`, and `else` chain is met, none of the other conditional statements are processed. Since your `else` block is not being executed, then you probably already met a previous `if` or `else if` statement's conditions. In order to check for two conditions independent of each other, simply use two separate `if` statements.

For example, in the code below, the word "World" and the "!" will not be printed, even though it is true that 5 is greater than 2 and that 4 is greater than 1:

```
if (5 > 2)
    System.out.print("Hello, ");
else if (4 > 1)
    System.out.print("World");
else
    System.out.print("!");
```

But, in the next example, both "Hello, " and "World" and "!" will be printed, because the three conditionals are independent of each other:

```
if (5 > 2)
    System.out.print("Hello, ");
if (4 > 1)
    System.out.print("World");
if (0 == 0)
    System.out.print("!");
```